# Why is my jQuery code endlessly repeating? Possible .bind problems?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, loops

I've been programming for a few months and making little scripts here and there for a site which has API and jQuery. Lately I have been working on a mini-rpg game for that site; unfortunately I am not exactly the most experienced person.

I encountered some problems with some .bind("click") jQuery events, mainly one in peculiar that won't stop and endlessly repeats. I made some buttons that should trigger more functions on click. I have a feeling I might be endlessly repeating between 2 functions, as some console.log messages are neverendingly repeating, crashing the tab in which I'm testing the code. I couldn't find what was the cause of the loop.

```js
//#initialFunctions
settingsButton();
menuButton();

//#buttons

function btnCloser(){
  if($('#btn1').length!==0){
    $('#btn1').remove();
    console.log("Btn1 removed.");
  }
  if($('#btn2').length!==0){
    $('#btn2').remove();
    console.log("Btn2 removed.");
  }
  if($('#btn3').length!==0){
    $('#btn3').remove();
    console.log("Btn3 removed.");
  }
}
function buttons3(){
  $('#mainWindow').append('<button id="btn1" type="button" style="position:absolute; top:105px; left:2.5px; width:240px; height:30px; background-color:black; color:white; opacity: 0.8; text-align:center;"></button>');
  $('#mainWindow').append('<button id="btn2" type="button" style="position:absolute; top:135px; left:2.5px; width:240px; height:30px; background-color:black; color:white; opacity: 0.8; text-align:center;"></button>');
  $('#mainWindow').append('<button id="btn3" type="button" style="position:absolute; top:165px; left:2.5px; width:240px; height:30px; background-color:black; color:white; opacity: 0.8; text-align:center;"></button>');
  $('#btn1').hover(function(){$('#btn1').css("cursor","pointer");$('#btn1').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #FFFFFF inset;");},function(){$('#btn1').css("cursor","auto");$('#btn1').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF inset;");});
  $('#btn2').hover(function(){$('#btn2').css("cursor","pointer");$('#btn2').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #FFFFFF inset;");},function(){$('#btn2').css("cursor","auto");$('#btn2').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF inset;");});
  $('#btn3').hover(function(){$('#btn3').css("cursor","pointer");$('#btn3').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #FFFFFF inset;");},function(){$('#btn3').css("cursor","auto");$('#btn3').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF inset;");});
}


//#buttonsUI

function menuButton(){
  $('body').append('<button id="menuBtn" type="button" onclick="menu()" style="position:absolute; top:55px; right:500px; width:100px; height:20px; background-color:black; color:white; opacity: 0.8; border-radius:20px; opacity: 0.8; z-index:100; font-size=200%; color:white; text-align:center;">Menu</button>');
  $('#menuBtn').hover(function(){$('#menuBtn').css("cursor","pointer");$('#closeButton').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #FFFFFF inset;");},function(){$('#menuBtn').css("cursor","auto");$('#closeButton').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF inset;");});
}

//#menu

maintenanceMode=false;
function menu(){
  $('statWindow').remove();
  if($('#mainWindow').length===0){
    $('body').append('<div id="mainWindow" style="position:absolute; top:90px; right: 355px; height: 200px; width: 250px; background-color: black; border: 2.5px solid #2FC7FB; border-radius: 20px; opacity: .8; z-index: 100;"></div>');
    $('#mainWindow').append('<div id="mainWindowText" style="position:absolute; top:12px; left:3px; text-align:left;"></div>');
    $('body').append('<div id="closeButton" onclick="mainWindowClose()" style="position: absolute; top:96px; right:360px; height:20px; width:20px; background-color:black; color:white; opacity: 0.8; opacity:0.8; z-index:101; font-size=170%; text-align:center; border: 2.5px solid #2FC7FB; border-radius: 10px;">X</div>');
    $('#closeButton').hover(function(){$('#closeButton').css("cursor","pointer");$('#closeButton').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #FFFFFF inset;");},function(){$('#closeButton').css("cursor","auto");$('#closeButton').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF inset;");});
  }
  btnCloser();
  buttons3();
  $('#btn1').bind("click",console.log("Stats button clicked.")).text('Stats');
  $('#btn2').bind("click",clinic()).text('Clinic');
  $('#btn3').bind("click",mainWindowClose()).text('Close');
}

//#mainUI

notShown=true;
function newWindow(){
  $('#miniGame').remove();
  notShown=false;
  $('body').append('<div id="mainWindow" style="position:absolute; top:90px; right: 355px; height: 200px; width: 250px; background-color: black; border: 2.5px solid #2FC7FB; border-radius: 20px; opacity: .8; z-index: 100;"></div>');
  $('#mainWindow').append('<div id="mainWindowText" style="position:absolute; top:12px; left:3px; text-align:left;"></div>');
  $('body').append('<div id="closeButton" onclick="mainWindowClose()" style="position: absolute; top:96px; right:360px; height:20px; width:20px; background-color:black; color:white; opacity: 0.8; opacity:0.8; z-index:101; font-size=200%; text-align:center; border: 2.5px solid #2FC7FB; border-radius: 10px;">x</div>');
  $('#closeButton').hover(function(){$('#closeButton').css("cursor","pointer");$('#closeButton').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #FFFFFF inset;");},function(){$('#closeButton').css("cursor","auto");$('#closeButton').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF inset;");});
  //$('#mainWindow').append('<button id="battleButton" type="button" onclick="clinicText()" style="position:absolute; top:160px; left:2.5px; width:240px; height:30px; background-color:black; color:white; opacity: 0.8; text-align:center;">Battle!</button>');
}
function showAlert(){
  $('body').append('<div id="miniGame" onclick="newWindow()" style="position:absolute; top:55px; right: 350px; height: 20px; width: 20px; background-color: red; border-radius:20px; opacity: 0.8; z-index: 100; font-size=500%; color: solid red; text-align: center;">!</div>');
  $('#miniGame').hover(function(){$('#miniGame').css("cursor","pointer");$('#miniGame').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 2px #FFFFFF inset;");},function(){$('#miniGame').css("cursor","auto");$('#miniGame').css("box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #FFFFFF inset;");});
  notShown=false;
  $('#miniGame').bind("click",monsterEncounter());
}
function mainWindowClose(){
  btnCloser();
  $('#mainWindow').remove();
  $('#closeButton').remove();
  notShown=true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It seems my code is somehow repeating over and over again and I wondered what were the causes. Thanks!

Comment: tldr ... http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When binding to an event, you need to provide a `function` that will be executed when the event occurs.. you appear to be passing the *result* of calling a function.

For example:

```
$('#btn1').bind("click",console.log("Stats button clicked."))
```

Is actually the same as

```
var x = console.log("Stats button clicked.");
$('#btn1').on('click', x);
```

which probably isn't what you intended.

Try this:

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function () {
    console.log('Stats button clicked.');
});
```

It is likely your `.hover(` handlers that are endlessly repeating tho.

Also, try breaking your code down and indenting it.. it's nice to see it all on one line, but it makes it hard to follow.  For example, in your `hover` function you have invalid javascript (which will likely be throwing errors in your console)